# Add links to scandir() results

Tags: php, scandir

I need to display scandir() results as links like:

```
 <a href="$scandir_result">$scandir_result</a>
```

It works great with one result, but with two or more, it echoes out the link as all the files in the directory. Like:

```
<a href='doc.pdfme.pdf.hello.pdf'>doc.pdf</a>
<a href='doc.pdfme.pdf.hello.pdf'>me.pdf</a>
<a href='doc.pdfme.pdf.hello.pdf'>hello.pdf</a>
```

Can I use a specific function for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results of scandir is an array so you need to go through the array to output each file as a separate link.

```
foreach ($scandir_result as $file) {

    echo '<a href="' . $file . '">' . $file . '</a>';

}  // end of foreach through the scandir results
```

Comment: If it helps and works please consider accepting the answer @JamesBaloyi

Answer (score 0):

use a loop

```
foreach ($scandir_result as $result) {
 echo "<a href=\"$result\">$result</a>"
}
```